# fadeToggle div, by clicking beside it

Tags: jquery

I have a div and i want to toggleFade it with jquery when the user clicks anywhere beside this div. How can i do this?

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to make it **fadeOut** or **toggleFade** when clicking outside of it?

Comment: toggleFade, because i am fading it in before this

Comment: Yes but if it is visible and you want to make it disappear you can simply use fadeOut.

Comment: okay, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

Lets say your body contains this div:

```
<a href="#show" id="showPopup">show</a>
<div class="popup">Popup</div>
```

Then you could try something like this:

```
$("#showPopup").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#popup").fadeIn(200);
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.target.className != "popup") {
        $(".popup").fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

In this solution we have an external wrapper which will cover all the width and height of the window, therefore, when we want to fadeOut the popup, we just have to test whether or not the user has clicked on the popup or on the wrapper. This can avoid also strange behaviour in case in the previous example if had clciked on other event handlers.

```js
$("#showPopup").on("click", function() {
    $("#popup-wrapper").fadeIn(200);
});

$("#popup-wrapper").on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "popup-wrapper")
        $("#popup-wrapper").fadeOut(200);
});
```

```css
#popup-wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}

#popup {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #efefef;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#show" id="showPopup">show</a>
<div id="popup-wrapper">
    <div id="popup">Popup</div>
</div>
```

Comment: because of having an id, i changed it to event.target.id. But it doesn't work, when fade my div in, it fades out immediately

Comment: I've edited the answer. You ave now two solutions. The one is almost the same as before, while the seconds is based on a "wrapper" containing the "popup" element.